# Displaying wordpress page with custom field

Tags: wordpress

I want to display two articles on a wordpress page (page.php), the main article and a secondary article in the sidebar. The secondary article is retrieved from a custom field with the post ID. I use this code:

```
            <?php

            $other_article = get_post_custom('secondaryarticle');

            if ($other_article > 0) {
                $show_article = get_post($other_article);
                $article_content = $show_article->post_content;
                echo $article_content;
            }?>
```

Each main article has a custom field with name secondaryarticle and the value is the post ID (for example 14). The code runs, there is no error message in php, but no article content is shown. Any tips?

Comment: Can you tell me what will be value of custom field secondaryarticle? Is it a post id or post tile?

Comment: Sorry late response, I thought I would receive an email when I received answers here. The secondaryarticle field will have a post ID as a value, e.g. 14.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a new sidebar and hook your custom field accordingly so it will show in the sidebar.

More from the codex link below:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Hope it helps.

Comment: This codex page talks about registering your sidebar in a widget enabled theme, but I am not using widgets here, I just use a normal include sidebar.php file that I call from index.php or page.php. So all I need to know is why the code I posted doesn't print the post content of my chosen post ID from my custom field. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I did this like this, and I didn't use any widgets, which was my goal. This code is hardcoded in the sidebar:

```
<div class="sidebar-article">
    <?php

    $secondary_article = get_post_custom('sidebararticle');

    if ($secondary_article > 0) {
        $show_article = get_post($secondary_article);
        $article_content = $show_article->post_content;
        echo $article_content;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Then you make a custom field on your main post/page article and call it "sidebararticle", with the post ID in the value field.